# Importing pfx certificate to selenoid firefox/edge image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, client-certificates, pfx, selenoid

I need to import client .pxf certificate inside selenoid container. For chrome I use following Dockerfile:

```
ARG IMAGE_VERSION
FROM selenoid/chrome:${IMAGE_VERSION}
ARG USER_ID
ARG USER_PASSWORD
COPY policy.json /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/policy.json
COPY ${USER_ID}.pfx .
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.pki/nssdb \
&& certutil -N -d $HOME/.pki/nssdb --empty-password \
&& pk12util -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -i ${USER_ID}.pfx -W ${USER_PASSWORD}
```

However the same approach doesn't work for microsoft edge and firefox. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong, but this script is exactly what I was looking for.